# How do special prosecutors leave their role?

Tags: united-states, judiciary, special-prosecutor

In the US, how do special prosecutors leave their role? Are they appointed for a limited time, do they resign or get fired?

I've looked at [Mueller's appointment letter](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/3726408-Rosenstein-letter-appointing-Mueller-special.html) but it doesn't mention a specific time frame (or at least not directly).

I've looked through 25 U.S.C. 509, 510 and 515 but I don't find any definitive answers. The closest is probably paragraph 15 saying the appointee is commissioned by the Attorney General.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A change in designation from Special Prosecutor to Special Counsel was made July 9, 1999. The Rules for the Special Counsel are in [28 CFR 600](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=28f9a33cf15632118467b6a4974270e0&mc=true&node=pt28.2.600&rgn=div5) under the Authority: 5 U.S.C. 301; 28 U.S.C. 509, 510, 515-519.

The Wikipedia article, [Special prosecutor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_prosecutor) covers this.

[Terminating a special counsel investigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_prosecutor#Terminating_a_special_counsel_investigation):

> Generally, the special counsel him or herself decides when an investigation will terminate, with or without formal charges being pursued. The special counsel typically issues a final report on their investigation at this time. The current special counsel regulations specify that[6] "At the conclusion of the Special Counsel's work, he or she shall provide the Attorney General with a confidential report explaining the prosecution or declination decisions reached by the Special Counsel."

28 CFR 600.8:

> (c) Closing documentation. At the conclusion of the Special Counsel's work, he or she shall provide the Attorney General with a confidential report explaining the prosecution or declination decisions reached by the Special Counsel.

Once the closing documentation has been provided the investigation is concluded.

Comment: That said, they may stick around a bit longer to do some administrative wrap-up.